# Add Stack Overflow's "homework" policy to the faq (next to about and logout at top of site)

Tags: feature-request, homework

We've had a lot of discussion on SO's homework policy: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework) [and here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow). So why don't we add this to faq? A link at the very least would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the very first page of the FAQ topics, you'll see that it does link to this thread:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: But that is not linked to on the official FAQ, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: The FAQ page needs to link to the actual FAQ documents.

Comment: the faq just to the left of the search bar :D